# Apache issues with socks redirection

Tags: linux, proxy, fedora, apache-http-server, socks-proxy

I have an issue with the socks configuration on my Fedora install and the LAMP environment.

I applied the solution to my question https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11947/securing-data-transfer-between-public-network-and-personal-accounts but now every time I try to access a development virtual hosts on my laptop, I get a 403 message because of the proxy setup.

Examples:

http.comf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/tests
   ServerName tests.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 tests.localhost
```

Access by `http://localhost/tests/` -> Ok, `http://tests.localhost/` -> 403

So, any ideas how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Look in your apache log files, specifically the error.log file to see more details as to what is causing the 403 error.  Once you have that post it to the questions and we can advise you further.  Normally located in /var/log/http(or apache2)/ directory.

Comment: that's what I first did, nothing... no clues there

Comment: Check permissions on the files and directory it is accessing.  Make sure the files and directory allow the user apache is running as to execute them and read them.  If the user and group are not the user running apache you will need to make them world readable and executable.

Comment: @Lipongo it isn't a Permissions issue, it's something else... with the proxy deactivated, I have no issue